# Help with VOIP registration timing out

Tags: networking, empathy, voip, ekiga

Not sure if this forum is correct, but I am trying to set up voip on Ubuntu 16.04 and I tried several apps (Ekiga, Linphone, Empathy), but they all time out when trying to register the account. I checked my voip credentials and they work on my phone, just not this computer.

I checked on wireshark and the registration requests always have the destination of 10.0.0.26.  As I understand it, that's an internal IP.

What's going on?

Comment: Temporarily turn off your firewall and see if it starts to work. Report back.

Comment: Didn't work, but i'm not too savvy with firewall stuff, so maybe I messed it up:  I installed gufw then went to every profile (home, public, and office) and set the status to "OFF".  Not sure if there is more to be done in that regard.

Comment: Oh, I also completely disabled the firewall (temporarily) on my router as well, still no luck.

Comment: Who's your VOIP carrier? Without giving me private information, what do your credentials look like... username/password... account #/password, etc? What are your VOIP servers set to? What port numbers?

Comment: All the credentials are correct as I did the same thing on my phone.  As for ports, I tried port forwarding them on my router but that didn't work either.